# How to Set Outlook in Work Offline Mode by VBA(Macro) Running From MS Word VBA UserForm

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I am trying to run a VBA code which it's supposed to let the user attach a file into a Mail Merge function.

In order to do this I need to put Outlook in Offline mode to keep the mails in outbox before attaching any files to mails.  Now I would like to know if there is a method to put Outlook 2007 in Offline mode from a Word Macro?

Answer (score 0):

First, add a reference to the Outlook Object Library.  If Outlook will already be open:

`Outlook.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.FindControl(, 5613).Execute`

if Outlook is closed:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders.GetFirst.GetExplorer.CommandBars.FindControl(, 5613).Execute
```